# Object that causes spacetime to expand?

Tags: gravity, cosmology, cosmological-inflation, dark-energy, cosmological-constant

Is there any thing that will cause spacetime to expand, so that particles are pushed away from them rather than pulled towards it. I know things such as black holes and planets causes dips and curve in spacetime, but is it possible that a celestial object will stretch spacetime?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_interaction_of_antimatter#Theories_of_gravitational_repulsion  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_energy#Effect_of_dark_energy:_a_small_constant_negative_pressure_of_vacuum  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casimir_effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only "known" content of the universe that can act this way is dark energy. Of course, ordinary matter, dark matter or radiation can't do this. From acceleration equation in a FRLW spacetime, you would need a component which satisfies a equation of state with $p<-\rho/3$. For matter, $p=0$, and for radiation $p=\rho/3$, both grater than $-\rho/3$, but for dark energy, $p=-\rho$, and it acts that way.

Comment: "For matter, $p = 0$, ..." -- for dust and some other special cases, not matter in general. One can't ignore pressure in, e.g., stars, esp. neutron stars.

Comment: You are right. I should have said non interacting matter.